# cnn with tf.layers - possible to get predicted class labels from tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec object?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Following this [Guide to TF Layers: Building a Convolutional Neural Network](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers#run_the_model)
I can see training and evaluation steps work correctly but I don't see how to get the predicted class labels for one unlableled dataset. I tried:

```
# try predict
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
  x={"x": my_test_data},
  num_epochs=1,
  shuffle=False)
test_results = mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn=test_input_fn)
print(test_results)
```

This produces a "generator object Estimator.predict at 0x00000000103DE990" that I couldn't manipulate to extract predictions.

Is it possible to get the predicted labels from this object? If no, how could one adapt this [cnn_model_fn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py) to make it return the predicted labels for a new unlabeled dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer. I'm posting it in cas it could help someone else:

```
for el in test_results:
    print(el)
```

this prints lables and probablities for every element in test data set.